# Proper installation of JSTL for Maven (Intellij IDEA)

Tags: maven, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea, jstl

I am trying to use JSTL for my index.jsp page, but for some reason each time after packaging project to .war and running with Tomcat it gives me following errors:

```
HTTP Status 500 - /index.jsp (line: 12, column: 0) Unterminated &lt;c:if tag
```

or

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
```

From what I found on google, there are 2 ways to install JSTL into your Maven project:
**1) Add this to pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**2) Add some jars to WEB-INF/lib, but here's the problem: no such folder was automaticaly created and if I do it manually it does not help. Project structure looks like this:**
[image]

The code of index.jsp is the following:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<title><c:if> Tag Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:set var="salary" scope="session" value="${2000*2}"/>
<c:if test="${salary > 2000}">
   <p>My salary is: <c:out value="${salary}"/><p>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

So, what should I do to make those work? I can't find any guide or piece of information that could help me solving this. Thanks for having a look at my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just what compiler tells you: **Unterminated c:if tag**:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<title><c:if> Tag Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:set var="salary" scope="session" value="${2000*2}"/>
<c:if test="${salary > 2000}">
   <p>My salary is: <c:out value="${salary}"/><p>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Look at line 4 of your jsp:

```
<title><c:if> Tag Example</title>
```

It must be

```
<title><c:if> Tag Example </c:if></title>
```

EDIT: As seems that I explained badly, I have tested in a running web-app, and this way (that is just what I was trying to explain) works:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>&lt;c:if&gt;  Tag Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:set var="salary" scope="session" value="${2000*2}"/>
<c:if test="${salary > 2000}">
   <p>My salary is: <c:out value="${salary}"/><p>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But this one is taken from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_if_tag.htm and I'm pretty sure it should work. If I remove <c:if> in 4th line the page shows nothing, so obviously the tag is not working.

Comment: You error claims about an unclosed c:if tag that is just what is there in line 4. Close it properly or delete it, otherwise it won't work

Comment: I did delete it and it still does not work properly. Now the page is just blank and gives neither error message, nor information I want. If I use this example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm, it shows `Item ${i}` 5 times instead of `Item 1` etc

Comment: Please have a look at my edit and test. I've just tested and it works this way

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, your solution seems to help, but now I have another problem. It looks like for some reason it just doesn't see variables or something, your edited example gives me a blank page, so that means that <c:if> is false, which of course can not be right. And, as I mentioned above, <c:forEach> gives wrong results as well, like it doesn't treat variable as a variable.

Comment: Found a solution. Changing `<web-app>` tab in web.xml helped:`<web-app
        version="3.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">`